# Video player high CPU usage

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, cpu-usage

I need to play a video file with **ffplay** in fullscreen mode. The original file has 720x576 resolution, my display is at 1920x1080.

When I launch **ffplay** as `ffplay "filename.avi"` and upscale it by maximizing its window, the resulting video looks pixelated. I think this is related to default image scaling algorithm used by **ffplay**.

When I launch it as `ffplay "filename.avi" -vf scale=1920x1080:sws_flags=lanczos+accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int+full_chroma_inp` and maximize the window, the result looks much better (anti-aliased, smooth edges), but CPU usage is at 25%.

At the same time, when I watch the same video in **Windows Media Player**, the result is as good as when upscaling the video in **ffplay**, but CPU usage is less than 5%.

How can I achieve the same result with **ffplay**?

Maybe it's because **Windows Media Player** upscales the video with GPU? If so, can **ffplay** use GPU too?

UPD: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037324/ffmpeg-frame-to-directx-surface-hardware-accelerated have something in common to my question?

Answer (score 2):

[FFPlay](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2009-February/066380.html) [does not support Hardware Acceleration.](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3359) This two year old feature request does not appear to have gotten much attention.

You can enable [Hardware Acceleration for FFMPeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) overall, but it does not appear to use it in `ffplay`.